# Google sheet filter add new spreadsheet row automatically

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large spreadsheet with multiple tabs. There is the main sheet that collects all the data entered through a form and then there are sub sheets with filtered information based on certain conditions like age for example. The sub sheets pull this data from the main sheet to which the form is linked using the FILTER() function. What I would like is for the google sheet to automatically add a new row with the filtered information each time a new entry is made. It does this for the main sheet where the form is linked, however for the filtered sub sheets you have to manually add new rows or the information will not populate. To be clear, I would like a new row added automatically containing the filtered information.

Comment: can you proide the filter() funtcino syntax you are using? If you don't specify the end row inside the function, you haven't anything to do, the new rows will be added automatically.

Comment: FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, …])

Comment: ok, but to be more clear, if you don't specify le rows in the formula, the new rows will be added

Answer (score 1):

If your formula is as follows

```
=filter('sheet with responses'!A:F;'sheet with responses'!C:C="criteria")
```

without specifying the rows, the new rows will be added in your filtered tabs.

Comment: could you explain in a bit more detail not sure I understand how this solves the problem I have.

Comment: can you provide a sample spreadsheet, it could be easier

Comment: have you tried my proposal? do you want me to create a spreadsheet?